# Why is my UIGestureRecognizer code not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

Why is the following code not working?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeLeft = 
[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeLeft:)];
[oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeRight = 
[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeRight:)];
[oneFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];

}

- (void)oneFingerSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{ 
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:[self view]];
NSLog(@"Swipe up - start location: %f,%f", point.x, point.y);
}

- (void)oneFingerSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{ 
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:[self view]];
NSLog(@"Swipe down - start location: %f,%f", point.x, point.y);
}
```

Bear in mind that I have lots of layers (e.g. images, buttons and labels) in front of the bare view. Would this make a difference? How can I make the gestures be recognised on top of all these layers?

Thanks!

Comment: this will solve your case... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402614/passing-a-touch-event-to-all-subviews-of-a-view-controller

Comment: i checked that codesnipet, its working for me

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava but I still don't understand what I need to do even after looking at that question :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to pass all the touches from the top of your subviews to your last view.. so add a transparent view and then pass all those touches to the main view as explained in the thread

[Passing a touch event to all subviews of a View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402614/passing-a-touch-event-to-all-subviews-of-a-view-controller)

Comment: could you provide some sample code because I don't understand how to do it...? I know you gave that link but it's not very clear exactly how to do it :)

Comment: Try something like this...

for (UIView *view in subviews)
  [view touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

The code above, in your touchesBegan method for example would pass the touches to all of the subviews of view.

Comment: this is what I've done - but it also has some errors: http://file.reddexuk.com/1g3p0N383h2C3f3v3e0c

Comment: you will have to implement all the touches delegate functions and perform the same in every method and also that link of yours is not working.

Comment: you need to learn a lot before you can start implementing such things.(looking at the error image) I just can't explain you everything here. Sorry that is the best I could do.

Answer (score 8):

Double check and make sure the UIView you are adding the UIGestureRecognizer to has `UserInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`. i.e.

`[self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`